# pass objects of class between activities with parcelable

Tags: android, class, object, parcelable

I'am trying to send a class object between two actvities with parcelable, it seems to be well applied,i have implement parcelable and then pass it via intent but my application stop whithout doing anything, i need some help!!

This is my class :

```
public class myTasks implements Parcelable {

String title_task, desc_task, prio_task, diff_task, date_task;

public myTasks(){
}

public myTasks(String title_task, String desc_task, String prio_task, String diff_task, String date_task) {
    this.title_task = title_task;
    this.desc_task = desc_task;
    this.prio_task = prio_task;
    this.diff_task = diff_task;
    this.date_task = date_task;
}

protected myTasks(Parcel in) {
    title_task = in.readString();
    desc_task = in.readString();
    prio_task = in.readString();
    diff_task = in.readString();
    date_task = in.readString();
}

public static final Creator<myTasks> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<myTasks>() {
    public myTasks createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new myTasks(in);
    }

    public myTasks[] newArray(int size) {
        return new myTasks[size];
    }
};

public String getTitle_task() {
    return title_task;
}

public void setTitle_task(String title_task) {
    this.title_task = title_task;
}

public String getDesc_task() {
    return desc_task;
}

public void setDesc_task(String desc_task) {
    this.desc_task = desc_task;
}

public String getPrio_task() {
    return prio_task;
}

public void setPrio_task(String prio_task) {
    this.prio_task = prio_task;
}

public String getDiff_task() {
    return diff_task;
}

public void setDiff_task(String diff_task) {
    this.diff_task = diff_task;
}

public String getDate_task() {
    return date_task;
}

public void setDate_task(String date_task) {
    this.date_task = date_task;
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
    parcel.writeString(title_task);
    parcel.writeString(desc_task);
    parcel.writeString(prio_task);
    parcel.writeString(diff_task);
    parcel.writeString(date_task);
}
```

}

This is the source Activity :

```
public class taskAdd extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView title_page, add_title, add_desc, add_date, add_prio, add_diff;
EditText title_task, desc_task, date_task, prio_task, diff_task;
//button
Button btn_save, btn_cancel;

ArrayList<myTasks> dataList;

//task counter
Integer task_num = new Random().nextInt();
String key_task = Integer.toString( task_num);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_task_add);

    //definition of the variables
    title_page = findViewById(R.id.title_page);

    add_title = findViewById(R.id.add_title);
    add_desc = findViewById(R.id.add_desc);
    add_date = findViewById(R.id.add_date);
    add_prio = findViewById(R.id.add_prio);
    add_diff = findViewById(R.id.add_diff);

    title_task = findViewById(R.id.title_task);
    desc_task = findViewById(R.id.desc_task);
    date_task = findViewById(R.id.date_task);
    prio_task = findViewById(R.id.prio_task);
    diff_task = findViewById(R.id.diff_task);

    btn_save = findViewById(R.id.btn_save);
    btn_cancel = findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel);
    /*#####################################################*/
    //recuperation of data
    btn_save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            //fil the object item_task with data
            myTasks task = new myTasks();

            task.setTitle_task(title_task.getText().toString());
            task.setDesc_task(desc_task.getText().toString());
            task.setPrio_task(prio_task.getText().toString());
            task.setDiff_task(diff_task.getText().toString());
            task.setDate_task(date_task.getText().toString());

            Log.i("TAG","Le titre de tâche est =" + " " +task.getTitle_task());

            Intent intent = new Intent(taskAdd.this,MainActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("parcel_data", task);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    /*#######################################################*/

    // import font
    Typeface MLight = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/ML.ttf");
    Typeface MMedium = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/MM.ttf");

    // customize font
    title_page.setTypeface(MMedium);

    add_title.setTypeface(MLight);
    title_task.setTypeface(MMedium);

    add_desc.setTypeface(MLight);
    desc_task.setTypeface(MMedium);

    add_date.setTypeface(MLight);
    date_task.setTypeface(MMedium);

    add_prio.setTypeface(MLight);
    prio_task.setTypeface(MMedium);

    add_diff.setTypeface(MLight);
    diff_task.setTypeface(MMedium);

    btn_save.setTypeface(MMedium);
    btn_cancel.setTypeface(MLight);
}
```

}

This is the target Activity :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView title_page, sub_title_page, end_page;
Button buttonNewTask;

// 1- Declare RecyclerView
RecyclerView ourtasks;

// 2- Declare arrayList of tasks & Adapter
ArrayList<myTasks> taskList;

tasksAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    title_page = findViewById(R.id.title_page);
    sub_title_page = findViewById(R.id.sub_title_page);
    end_page = findViewById(R.id.end_page);

    buttonNewTask = findViewById(R.id.buttonNewTask);

    // import font
    Typeface MLight = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/ML.ttf");
    Typeface MMedium = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/MM.ttf");

    // customize font
    title_page.setTypeface(MMedium);
    sub_title_page.setTypeface(MLight);
    end_page.setTypeface(MLight);

    //button font
    buttonNewTask.setTypeface(MLight);

    buttonNewTask.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //start a task add activity when button pressed
            Intent a = new Intent(MainActivity.this,taskAdd.class);
            startActivity(a);
        }
    });

    //working with data
    ourtasks = findViewById(R.id.ourtasks);
    ourtasks.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    taskList = new ArrayList<myTasks>();


    myTasks task = (myTasks) getIntent().getParcelableExtra("parcel_data");

    taskList.add(task);
    Log.i("TAG","===========================" + " " +task.getPrio_task());

    adapter = new tasksAdapter(MainActivity.this,taskList);
    ourtasks.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

}

stack trace of logcat

`2020-04-11 13:14:50.259 24573-24573/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
2020-04-11 13:14:50.259 24573-24573/? I/art: Reinit property: dalvik.vm.checkjni= false
2020-04-11 13:14:50.303 24573-24580/? E/art: Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
2020-04-11 13:14:50.304 24573-24580/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
2020-04-11 13:14:50.304 24573-24580/? I/art: Starting a blocking GC Instrumentation
2020-04-11 13:14:50.375 24573-24573/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/comt.example.farida.taskand-2/lib/arm64
2020-04-11 13:14:50.376 24573-24573/? W/art: JIT profile information will not be recorded: profile file does not exits.
2020-04-11 13:14:50.384 24573-24573/? I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
2020-04-11 13:14:50.397 24573-24573/? I/HwCust: Constructor found for class android.app.HwCustActivityImpl
2020-04-11 13:14:50.410 24573-24573/? I/HwCust: Constructor found for class android.app.HwCustHwWallpaperManagerImpl
2020-04-11 13:14:50.421 24573-24573/? W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
2020-04-11 13:14:50.438 24573-24573/? I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat$OnUnhandledKeyEventListenerWrapper>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/view/View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener;
2020-04-11 13:14:50.438 24573-24573/? I/art:     at void android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(android.view.View, android.support.v4.view.OnApplyWindowInsetsListener) (ViewCompat.java:2203)
2020-04-11 13:14:50.438 24573-24573/? I/art:     at android.view.ViewGroup android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:637)
2020-04-11 13:14:50.438 24573-24573/? I/art:     at void android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:518)
2020-04-11 13:14:50.438 24573-24573/? I/art:     at void android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(int) (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:466)
2020-04-11 13:14:50.438 24573-24573/? I/art:     at void android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) (AppCompatActivity.java:140)
2020-04-11 13:14:50.438 24573-24573/? I/art:     at void comt.example.farida.taskand.SplashScreen.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (SplashScreen.java:13)
2020-04-11 13:14:50.438 24573-24573/? I/art:     at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:6912)
2020-04-11 13:14:50.438 24573-24573/? I/art:     at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1123)
2020-04-11 13:14:50.438 24573-24573/? I/art:     at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2746)
2020-04-11 13:14:50.438 24573-24573/? I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2864)
2020-04-11 13:14:50.438 24573-24573/? I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
2020-04-11 13:14:50.438 24573-24573/? I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1567)
2020-04-11 13:14:50.438 24573-24573/? I/art:     at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:102)
2020-04-11 13:14:50.438 24573-24573/? I/art:     at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:156)
2020-04-11 13:14:50.438 24573-24573/? I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6520)
2020-04-11 13:14:50.438 24573-24573/? I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
2020-04-11 13:14:50.438 24573-24573/? I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:941)
2020-04-11 13:14:50.438 24573-24573/? I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:831)
2020-04-11 13:14:50.438 24573-24573/? I/art: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/comt.example.farida.taskand-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/comt.example.farida.taskand-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/comt.example.farida.taskand-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/comt.example.farida.taskand-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/comt.example.farida.taskand-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/comt.example.farida.taskand-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/comt.example.farida.taskand-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/comt.example.farida.taskand-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/comt.example.farida.taskand-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/comt.example.farida.taskand-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/comt.example.farida.taskand-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/comt.example.farida.task
2020-04-11 13:14:50.438 24573-24573/? I/art:     at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
2020-04-11 13:14:50.438 24573-24573/? I/art:     at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:380)
2020-04-11 13:14:50.438 24573-24573/? I/art:     at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
2020-04-11 13:14:50.438 24573-24573/? I/art:     at void android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(android.view.View, android.support.v4.view.OnApplyWindowInsetsListener) (ViewCompat.java:2203)
2020-04-11 13:14:50.438 24573-24573/? I/art:     at android.view.ViewGroup android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:637)
2020-04-11 13:14:50.438 24573-24573/? I/art:     at void android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:518)
2020-04-11 13:14:50.438 24573-24573/? I/art:     at void android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(int) (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:466)
2020-04-11 13:14:50.438 24573-24573/? I/art:     at void android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) (AppCompatActivity.java:140)
2020-04-11 13:14:50.438 24573-24573/? I/art:     at void comt.example.farida.taskand.SplashScreen.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (SplashScreen.java:13)
2020-04-11 13:14:50.438 24573-24573/? I/art:     at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:6912)
2020-04-11 13:14:50.438 24573-24573/? I/art:     at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1123)
2020-04-11 13:14:50.438 24573-24573/? I/art:     at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2746)
2020-04-11 13:14:50.438 24573-24573/? I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2864)
2020-04-11 13:14:50.438 24573-24573/? I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
2020-04-11 13:14:50.438 24573-24573/? I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1567)
2020-04-11 13:14:50.438 24573-24573/? I/art:     at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:102)
2020-04-11 13:14:50.438 24573-24573/? I/art:     at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:156)
2020-04-11 13:14:50.438 24573-24573/? I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6520)
2020-04-11 13:14:50.438 24573-24573/? I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
2020-04-11 13:14:50.438 24573-24573/? I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:941)
2020-04-11 13:14:50.438 24573-24573/? I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:831)
2020-04-11 13:14:50.445 24573-24573/? I/BitmapFactory: set decoder allocator to gralloc
2020-04-11 13:14:50.446 24573-24573/? I/gralloc: alloc_device_alloc:564: Alloc handle(0x7d51484900): interfmt=1, stride=1024, size=2457600, usage=0x2000003
2020-04-11 13:14:50.457 24573-24573/? I/gralloc: alloc_device_alloc:564: Alloc handle(0x7d4191b000): interfmt=1, stride=3008, size=21659648, usage=0x2000003
2020-04-11 13:14:50.520 24573-24573/? I/gralloc: alloc_device_free:586: Free handle(0x7d4191b000)
2020-04-11 13:14:50.520 24573-24573/? I/gralloc: alloc_device_free:586: Free handle(0x7d51484900)
2020-04-11 13:14:50.533 24573-24573/? I/HwSecImmHelper: mSecurityInputMethodService is null
2020-04-11 13:14:50.536 24573-24573/? I/HwPointEventFilter: support AFT
2020-04-11 13:14:50.573 24573-24595/? I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
2020-04-11 13:14:50.577 24573-24595/? W/linker: /vendor/lib64/libhwuibp.so: unused DT entry: type 0xf arg 0xe3a
2020-04-11 13:14:54.609 24573-24573/comt.example.farida.taskand I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 24573 SIG: 9`

Comment: @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        
        ourtasks = findViewById(R.id.ourtasks);
        ourtasks.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        taskList = new ArrayList<myTasks>();

        myTasks task = (myTasks) getIntent().getParcelableExtra("parcel_data");

        taskList.add(task);

        adapter = new tasksAdapter(MainActivity.this,taskList);
        ourtasks.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

Comment: @BömachtBlau i have just added !! thanks

Comment: If your app suddenly "stops", then I suppose it crashes. Please add the stack trace (from Logcat) as well.

Comment: @BömachtBlau I I added that too!!

Comment: Those logs are likely unrelated to your crash. You're looking for [the stack trace from the crash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23353174), which should be a large section of red lines, starting with `FATAL EXCEPTION`. You can use the filters above the log window to make it easier to find.

Comment: @MikeM. i didn't see any FATAL EXCEPTION, actually, I add a class for splash screen, so it starts whith that normally, then when it gets to the main activity the apps crashes. the only errors shown in red is : Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe

Comment: Well, if you can't find that, then you're probably gonna have to start manually debugging this. I would start by temporarily removing/commenting everything in `MainActivity`'s `onCreate()` after the `setContentView()` call, and see if that crashes. If it doesn't, then start adding things back one by one, until it crashes again.

Comment: thank you for your answer, actually all work well, but just when i add a line to use the recovered object, the application craches. for example when i want to display the content of the recovered object the app crashes.

Comment: I kinda figured that might be where the problem is. When you first start up, you haven't passed anything to `MainActivity`, so `getIntent().getParcelableExtra("parcel_data")` is going to return `null`. Then you add that `null` to your `taskList`, and then pass that list to the `Adapter`, which is probably not expecting a `null` value, so it ends up throwing a `NullPointerException`. Either check first if `task` is null, or use `getIntent().hasExtra("parcel_data")` to see if it's even on there.

Comment: You might also have a look into `startActivityForResult()`/`onActivityResult()`, which you could use to start your `taskAdd`, and then return a result back to the original `MainActivity`, instead of continually starting new Activities each time you add a task.

Comment: ok, i will try that, thank you for your for you time